# How do I output the link to the content?

Tags: views, theming

In a view, I've got a field set up to output the link to the content.

[image: Link To Content]

I'm not sure how to reference it in my views-view-fields.html.twig file. I'm referencing all of the other fields values properly as they all work, but that main anchor link just isn't coming out. What is the proper syntax?

```
 <a href="{{ fields.link_to_content.value }} "><!--start smallbox link-->
 <div style="background-color:grey" class="smallestboxes"><!--start small box 2::::image 1st then text-->
 <div class="container"><!--start container-->
 <div class="content"><!--start content div-->
 <div class="content-overlay" id="clienthover"></div>
 {{ fields.uri.content }}
 <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom" id="worktext"><!--start fade in-->
 <h1>{{fields.field_work_page_tagline.content}}</h1>
 <p>{{fields.title.content}}</p>
 </div><!--end fade in-->
 </div><!--end content div-->
 </div><!--end container-->
 </div><!--end smallest box 2--></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ fields.view_node.content }}` displays the value of *Content: Link to Content* view field.
It works for me when I use that line in the *views-view-fields.html.twig* template file.